# Session Time out problem

Tags: asp.net

Dear All
I have a website hosted on the cloud server and I have added 
**sessionState mode ="InProc" timeout="1440" />**
in the **web.config** file. But the session gets timed out in 1-2 minutes.
I think the web.config settings should override the IIS settings.But it's not working. Is there solution for this?

thanks in advance

Anoop George Thomas

Comment: Have you checked what are the definitions on IIS?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475019/session-time-out-even-after-setting-in-web-config-and-iis

Answer (score 1):

With InProc (in-memory) session state, you will lose session if any of the following conditions occur:

- IIS worker process restarts
- User is transferred to another worker process on the same webserver, or another webserver
- IIS restarts

I would verify that you are not seeing any strange restart behavior on IIS, or if you are bouncing around in your cloud environment.

Answer (score 0):

If your using Forms authentication this has a timeout as well.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
       <forms timeout="20"/>
</authentication>
```